# pickerView fails loading JSON data that fetch from Alamofire 4.8.2 using SwiftyJSON in Swift 5 code

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, uipickerview, swift5

I am calling API to fill the data in `UIPickerView` using **Swift 5** and **Alamofire 4.8.2**.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var my_array = [[String : AnyObject]]()

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerArray: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let url = URL(string:"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all") else {
            return
        }

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (resData) -> Void in

            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(resData.result.value!)
                print("Full Output", swiftyJsonVar)
            let finalData = swiftyJsonVar[0]["callingCodes"].arrayValue
                print("final data", finalData)
            let finalData2 = swiftyJsonVar[0]["borders"].arrayValue
                print("single dimensional array output: ", finalData2)
            let sampData = JSON(resData.result.value!)
            self.my_array = finalData2 as [AnyObject] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
            self.pickerArray.reloadAllComponents()                
        }

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return my_array.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return my_array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        labelName.text = "You Selected : " + my_array[row]
    }
}
```

Finally, I need that
 * "*finalData2*" result into my picker view
 *  also any data I need to take from that nested JSON data and pass to picker view

Comment: can anyone help me for getting the solution Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to be displayed in the picker view?

Comment: any data from json

Comment: let finalData2 = swiftyJsonVar[0]["borders"].arrayValue.. here I mentioned "borders" data to display in picker view. First I need borders data to display in picker view then any data from the above api "Json"  too

Comment: Usually in a picker view the data source is an array and you see one string per line. Please elaborate what you want to select. And you have an array of borders for each country.

Comment: You are missing `pickerArray.delegate = self`. Please write that in your `viewDidLoad()` method

Comment: I want to fetch "borders" data to pickerView dynamcially

Comment: Can you show the "borders" array what it contains and what you want to show on the picker view title?

Comment: The JSON is an array of countries and each country contains an array of borders. You cannot display them all. In your code you are going to display only the borders of the first country.

Comment: In my code as you said I showed only the output of 1st border array. I need all borders to dimply in picker view. that is enough

Comment: If you want to display all borders of a country in the picker view you have to flatten the array for example Afghanistan could display `"IRN, PAK, TKM, UZB, TJK, CHN"` as **one** string. Is that what you want?